# I cannot validate a CSRF token

Tags: 10

I have created a Rest API to create a user after success full user creation created CSRF token for the further user access. created csrf token using below core functions. using get() - function i am able to get a csrf token.

```php
public function get($value = '') {
  $seed = $this->sessionMetadata->getCsrfTokenSeed();
  if (empty($seed)) {
    $seed = Crypt::randomBytesBase64();
    $this->sessionMetadata->setCsrfTokenSeed($seed);
  }

  return $this->computeToken($seed, $value);
}
```

I cannot validate it, though, because `$this->sessionMetadata->getCsrfTokenSeed()` always returns an empty value.

```php
public function validate($token, $value = '') {
  $seed = $this->sessionMetadata->getCsrfTokenSeed();
  if (empty($seed)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
    
  $value = $this->computeToken($seed, $value);
    
  if (!is_string($token)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
    
  return hash_equals($value, $token);
}
```

Comment: I have fixed it. by default system is predefined the parameters
->get('rest'); this works fine